# Docker-compose logging issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was trying to save a file with the container logs using "logging" and "driver: local" in my docker-compose.

example:

```
# Application service
      r4i2:
              depends_on:
                      - mongodb
              build:
                      context: ./app
              env_file:
                      - .env
              container_name: app
              ports:
                      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
              volumes:
                      - ./app/app_srcs/public/:/app/public/
              networks:
                      - honey-net
              logging:
                      driver: "local"
```

But now I'm searching this file and I don't know where is, someone can help me please?

Where is the file?
Can I rename the file?
Can I change the path?